# creating an event in ios calendar using ekeventeditcontroller does not send mail to some invitees

Tags: ios, ekevent, ekeventkit

[image: add invitees page screenshot]

when inviting invitees over email for an event created with ekediteventcontroller some invitees are not getting invite emails.also when inviting people for some emails a question mark is shown. For these people the mails are not going. Can someone explain what does this question mark represent?